# Quarkus SmallRye-JWT JSON Web Key Sets refresh-interval

Tags: java, jwt, quarkus, smallrye, quarkus-oidc

I am using SmallRye JWT to generate and verify the JWT token. 
With microservice A, I generate the JWT token. 
With microservice B, I have to verify the JWT token. 
Inside microservice B, I use the properties:

```html
smallrye:
  jwt:
    verify:
      key:
        location: http://localhost:8084/key
    jwks:
      refresh-interval: 2
      forced-refresh-interval: 2
  token:
    kid: 123452
```

And microservice A has the endpoint /key that produces the JWKS:

```html
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "kid": "123452",
      "n": "i7y5smIoGrMHAQnwef7DfhSsrm-locPO_I1LkKHHVb4ol_Tfu3Me5uswb7M92H_A1Mhub4Zsugy22OqKVNnX9Z9UDpu4yG-KfPJRNNI9Rzo0fIBHzf8_g_cIdiNJJbODndxVAr4I38ZcFV6rSw",
      "e": "AQAB"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run both microservices at the same time, I am able to verify the token in microservice B...but if I restart microservice A (it will generate another JWKS) but microservice B will not be able anymore to verify the JWT token.
Inside the SmallRye - Quarkus documentation, I found the following properties:

> smallrye.jwt.jwks.refresh-interval: JWK cache refresh interval in
> minutes. It will be ignored unless the
> mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location points to the HTTP or HTTPS URL based
> JWK set and no HTTP Cache-Control response header with a positive
> max-age parameter value is returned from a JWK set endpoint.

and

> smallrye.jwt.jwks.forced-refresh-interval: orced JWK cache refresh
> interval in minutes which is used to restrict the frequency of the
> forced refresh attempts which may happen when the token verification
> fails due to the cache having no JWK key with a kid property matching
> the current token’s kid header. It will be ignored unless the
> mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location points to the HTTP or HTTPS URL based
> JWK set.

As you can see, I set up both properties to 2 minutes:

```html
smallrye:
  jwt:
    verify:
      key:
        location: http://localhost:8084/key
    jwks:
      refresh-interval: 2
      forced-refresh-interval: 2
  token:
    kid: 123452
```

but it not works.

What do I do to make it works?
I would like to call again the key.location (http://localhost:8084/key) to read again the new JKWS.

Thank you.

Comment: "*smallrye.jwt.jwks.refresh-interval: JWK cache refresh interval in minutes. **It will be ignored unless the `mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location` points to the HTTP or HTTPS URL** based JWK set and no HTTP Cache-Control response header with a positive max-age parameter value is returned from a JWK set endpoint.*" - Have you set `mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location`?

Comment: Thank you @Turing85. but it not works.  mp:
  jwt:
    verify:
      publickey:
        location: http://localhost:8084/key

Comment: io.smallrye.jwt.auth.principal.ParseException: SRJWT07000: Failed to verify a token

Comment: @Turing85 Is there any possibility to refresh the the JWT key store without pointing to a HTTP(S) URL? When I modify the referenced file, because I perform a key rotation, I need to refresh it (without a restart of all services).